# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to test an Angular Component using the ActivatedRoute Class in Karma/Jasmine but I'm having a very annoying error that I can't fix. `Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

I have tried all solutions I found online, mocking an Activated Route in various ways. But I just can't get it to work.

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActivatedRoute, convertToParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

import { SearchbarComponent } from './searchbar.component';

describe('SearchbarComponent', () => {
  let component: SearchbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchbarComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule ],
      declarations: [ SearchbarComponent ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            queryParams: of(convertToParamMap({ 
              search: ""         
            }))
          }
        }
    ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

```js
import { Input, Component, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
...
@Component({
  selector: 'searchbar',
  templateUrl: './searchbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searchbar.component.scss'],
  providers: [ ActivatedRoute ]
})
export class SearchbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.route.queryParams
    .subscribe(params => {
        this.currentSearch = params.search;
    });
  }
...
}
```

Comment: It would be beneficial for you and the community to finish the introductory tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour. It helps to understand what info to provide and how to ask questions to have a better chance of finding help. And would give you a badge (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RouterTestingModule` handles the mocks of all the routing-related things, including ActivatedRoute. You can delete the `providers` section and I would expect it to work

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActivatedRoute, convertToParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

import { SearchbarComponent } from './searchbar.component';

describe('SearchbarComponent', () => {
  let component: SearchbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchbarComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule ],
      declarations: [ SearchbarComponent ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok thats half the truth. Also check if you put any stupid providers in the component like I did. Removing `providers: [ActivatedRoute]` fixed it.